# How to find the inverse of the complex function $ f(z)=\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^{2}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, inverse-function

I'm trying to calculate the inverse function of :
$$ f(z)=\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^{2}}}$$ where  $z\in$ $\mathbb{C}$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, I was meaning the function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the inverse, $1-|f|^2=\frac{1}{1+|z|^2}\implies z=f\sqrt{1+|z|^2}=\frac{f}{\sqrt{1-|f|^2}}$.

Comment: Yeah , I can see it, thank you.